# AttributeError in beautifulsoup

Tags: python, beautifulsoup

To fetch the link of announcement page for the company news.

```
self.more_anno_link = PREFIX_URL + str(self.soup.find("div", attrs{"class":"PT5 gL_11", "align":"right"}).find("a")["href"])
```

While running gives the following error, I got below error:

```
AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'find'
```

Comment: So am i providing wrong attributes?

Comment: Please post your html or share the url?

Answer (score 0):

```
self.soup.find("div", attrs{"class":"PT5 gL_11", "align":"right"}).find("a")["href"]
```

if this part not found it return None:

```
a = self.soup.find("div", attrs{"class":"PT5 gL_11", "align":"right"})
```

So you can't then get:

```
a.find("a")["href"]
```